# Dynamically set input and output paths in pig using UDFs

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to create a no-arg pig script that dynamically creates input and output paths. 
The script itself should determine a input file glob based on current date and similarly determine an output file path based on current date. While I know that one can easily pass in parameters I was hoping to have a no-arg script and use a couple of simple jython UDFs to compute these paths.
How do I do that? I can't seem to set variables by calling a UDF. For instance,

> %default OUTPUTPATH myfn();

or

> path = myfn();

don't seem to work.

Any ideas?

(Why no-args? Because I would like to have a single static amazon data pipeline config that runs the same script each day but under the hood would run the last day's or last week's worth of log files each time.)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, to my knowledge, there is no way to do this in pure pig.  However, you can define these changing variables in a [python wrapper](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/cont.html#embed-python). In your case, you'll just define the dict of args like:

```
d = {
     'OUTPATH': myfn(),
    }
```

And then pass that dict like:

```
P = Pig.compile(path_to_my_script)

Q = P.bind(d)

results = Q.run()
```

Of course there is a little more to add to the wrapper, but it should be pretty clear from the docs.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback. As I would be running this on amazon EMR, controlled through a data pipeline JSON config file, I don't think that I have that level of configurability to run embedded python like this. However, one workaround in my case would be to create a pig script template, swap out the paths and upload this to S3 with the same filename each day. That would be very simple to implement.